# Different input formats in OPA when query using rest api vs local tool

Tags: json, yaml, open-policy-agent

When evaluating a query in Open Policy Agent (OPA) using local tool with *opa eval* command the input of the query is just a normal json/yaml.
Ex input yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx
```

But when evaluate a query using opa **rest api** the json/yaml value has to be embedded under a key called ***input***. Ex :

```
input:
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: nginx-pod
    labels:
      app: nginx
```

If the value is read from a file then the key **input** also needed to included which is not suitable in some applications where yaml files are manifests.

I want to know whether my approach to query opa rest api is correct and whether there exist a methed where the key **input** is not needed when query using opa rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the main difference between v0 (no input) and v1 (input) of the [data API](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#data-api). Simply replace `/v1/data/` in your query with `/v0/data`. See the [docs](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#get-a-document-webhook) for further details.